# Intellisense in Visual Studio Code for Object pascal with reference into c# compiled dll

Tags: c#, dll, visual-studio-code, delphi, omnipascal

There is my problem: I´m trying to use **Intellisense** in **Visual Studio Code** in Object pascal language, where some of the main classes are in the **C# Dll library** a I´m using OmniPascal Extension. Is there any chance to get a **reference to this Dll** (like in Visual Studio) so the intellisense could start working? Or is there another way?

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to get the symbols from the C# DLL to appear in OmniPascal's code completion automatically.
You need to declare the DLL's interfaces in one or more `.pas` files. OmniPascal will add their interfaces to code completion when you add these units to the `uses` clauses.